# How do I copy an image link if I can't see the option in the context menu?

Tags: google-chrome

Say I go to [a page on eBay](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/Chieftec-Dragon-PC-Case-/300720667770?pt=UK_Computing_DesktopComponents_RL&hash=item4604593c7a#ht_500wt_949) (but this applies to any or at least many websites, so it's not eBay specific) and I want to view pictures and save them..

I move my mouse over to the pic I right click, and there's no way I can currently see to copy the image URL and no way to save the image.  'Save as' brings up a webpage save.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

go to the developer tools by pressing shift+ctrl+i ... and then select the resources tab .. and on the left hand side .. expand 'frames' and then finally expand 'Images' and there you can find all the images that have been used in site...

**Image added by barlop**
[image]

Comment: looks like your answer is true to the most recent chrome update, as of writing.

Answer (score 6):

Looks like some JavaScript sorcery is preventing you from saving an image that you clearly see!

In Google Chrome, you can use a workaround in **Developer Tools** (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> or Tools >> Developer Tools) to capture the images as they are being downloaded.

1. In Developer Tools, choose the "Network" tab.
2. Select the "Images" filter at the bottom.
3. Reload the page.
4. Scroll through the images captured and find the one(s) that you want.

[image]

Comment: It could also be CSS: a floating, transparent `div` element could be between your mouse and the image.

Comment: True, but in this site's case, I checked the source code, and the image isn't under a transparent `<div>` at its expected location, so I think it has to be some JavaScript.

Comment: Nicely done.  IE doesn't have the problem with the javascript, maybe just Chrome.

Comment: @barlop This is not a Chrome bug, it's obviously an IE bug. The intention of the Javascript is that the image URL can't be copied that easily.

Comment: @Deltik Look closer! Below the `<div>` that contains the `<img>`, there is another `<div style="height:498px;width:498px;">`. If you delete this element, you can save/copy the image as usual. But I agree, the `Network` tab will always show all images.

Comment: Oh hello.  Yeah, I see it now.  **Alternative answer:** If you know HTML and know how to use the "Elements" tab in Developer Tools, you may be able to find the `<img>` tag that contains the image that you want.

Comment: your answer's great. But as to the alternative, of going to the HTML and finding the img tag, that's inefficient. there may be many image links and it's not quick to go through them manually. like copying each link and pasting it into a tab.  infact my original question pre it was edited, asked for a -good way-.(of course e.g. not one that'd take ages). You provided a good way, and it's a very cool way too!

Comment: Looks like Chrome has updated it now.. This seems a bit unfair but I have switched my answer to one that has just been posted that shows how to do it now.  Your answer is well deserving of the +1s though.. As for the <img> tag in elements, how does one find them quickly and see the images? I did ctrl-f <img> and it highlighted them but didn't scroll the main page to show them and I can't see previews

Answer (score 4):

You could try drag and drop of the image to your desktop (or other folder). The image file is copied automatically.

If all fails, a simple: ALT+Print Screen will capture your active window.

Comment: +1 "You could try drag and drop of the image to your desktop (or other folder). The image file is copied automatically."  Nicely done.  it's not copying the link but still fantastic!

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using firefox, try `CTRL+I` and it will open page info, then look for the image url and copy it in your address bar.
  It will load just the image.
- Or You can use firebug instead.